# fullPage.js onLoad callback?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, fullpage.js

I've been using fullPage.js for a project and there's an event that I need to execute AS SOON as the next section is loaded (not after it has finished loading). Is there a way to do this? I can't seem to find something like that in the [documentation](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js).

The only callbacks listed are:

- afterLoad (anchorLink, index)
- onLeave (index, nextIndex, direction)
- afterRender()
- afterResize()
- afterSlideLoad (anchorLink, index, slideAnchor, slideIndex)
- onSlideLeave (anchorLink, index, slideIndex, direction)

The main idea would be to add a class to an element as soon as I'm moving to another section. If there isn't a callback predefined to do so, which would be the best way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`onLeave`](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js#onleave-index-nextindex-direction):

**onLeave (index, nextIndex, direction)**
This callback is fired once the user leaves a section, in the transition to the new section.

Using the `nextIndex` parameter you can do what you want to achieve.